# How to play a non-rtmp stream

Tags: stream, protocols, rtmp, video.js

I have an issue to stream a video conference for many mobile device(Andriod, iPhone etc) and I have troubles with streaming.
RTMP stream uses a flash and didn't work with this devices.
What stream can I use? and how can I convert rtmp to this supported stream?

Answer (score 0):

For mobile devices you would need to convert your video to HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). If it's truly a live stream, you could use something [Zencoder live streaming](http://zencoder.com/en/live-transcoding) to convert it. If the RTMP stream is just reading from an MP4, you could use Handbrake or Zencoder to transmux it to HLS.

Comment: Thank you!
I will use nginx-rtmp-module. It can send rtmp to HLS.
And HLS support on most Android devices.